# I tried to insert data in mysql database using C# txtbox form but I always got an error?

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

This is my code I think I am doing right so far but I really dunno what is the problem.
I am making a register form with txtbox for username and password I encrypt the password with MD5, I tried deleting the MD5 encryption thinking that it might be the prtoblem but still when I deleted it the problem is still occur.

```
ApareceCrudLib a = new ApareceCrudLib("localhost", "root", "",  "cashieringdb");

            string query = "INSERT INTO register (username,password) " +
                          "VALUES(" +
                           "'" + txtUser.Text + "'," +
                           "MD5('" + txtPass.Text +"')";
            a.mysqlInsert(query);
            MessageBox.Show("Account has been registered!");
            this.Close();
```

This is the code for my class ApareceCrudLib for mysqlInsert

```
 public void mysqlInsert(string query)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.Open())
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    this.Close();
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted!");
                }
            }
            catch { this.Close(); System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("INSERT Record Error!"); }
            return;
        }
```

as you can see I catch the error with dialog box so basically if it will fail to insert or connect to database the message box shows "INSERT Record Error!". By the way there is no error in visual studio only in inserting to database.

I think the error somewhere in the code for inserting database string query = "INSERT

```
INTO register (username,password) " +
                              "VALUES(" +
                               "'" + txtUser.Text + "'," +
                               "MD5('" + txtPass.Text +"')";
```

maybe a comma a semi-colon a period I am clueless.

Hi!rhughes here is the image of the error!

[image]

Comment: as you can see I catch the error with dialog box so basically if it will fail to insert or connect to database the message box shows "INSERT Record Error!". By the way there is no error in visual studio only in inserting to database.

Comment: The answers are correct, and the exception message would have shown you that. Knowing there's an error isn't enough; you need to know what the error actually is.

Comment: Since you are willing to learn, you also might want to read about SQL Injection. You are using the input from the user directly in your sql statement this can be very dangerous

Comment: In regards to your edit, you're looking for an extra bracket on the end: "MD5('" + txtPass.Text +"'))";

Comment: Thanks for the update. As @mdvlpr said, you are missing a ')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL is not correct. You have two opening "("  and only one closing.

Comment: hahaha oh yes thank you how stupid I am I search every syntax for the error and forgot to notice the closing hahahhahahahaha

Answer (score 3):

you must add a ")" to your string query.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO register (username,password) " +
                      "VALUES(" +
                       "'" + txtUser.Text + "'," +
                       "MD5('" + txtPass.Text +"'))";
                                                  ^ HERE
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the actual error, try this:

```
try
{
    if (this.Open())
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.Close();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted!");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    this.Close();
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String.Format("INSERT Record Error! {0}", ex.Message));
}
```